# Can Pawn Sacrifice deal 6 damage to a single creature?

Tags: keyforge

If my opponent plays Pawn Sacrifice while he and I each have one creature, mine being power 5, first he sacrifices his creature, then he deals 3 damage to mine. Does the second instance of damage also go to my creature, or does it fizzle because "each" implies 2 different targets?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot deal 6 damage to a single creature. Here's the response from Brad Andres (developer at FFG):

> The second instance of damage does indeed “fizzle” because pawn
>   sacrifice indicates with the “each to 2 creatures” phrase that you
>   must choose 2 creatures and not the same creature twice. Hope that
>   helps!